# How to batch upload files to Google fusion tables?

Tags: csv, batch-processing, google-fusion-tables

I have a number of individual files (~40) that i want to upload to and create Fusion tables out of. All files are csv and can be uploaded individually. Is it possible to upload this in some form of batch way by specifying directory or something like this.

I am not a programming expert but understand enough to get a batch process going. I do not want to however use POST etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the API allows interacting only through GETs and POSTs.

Comment: Yes and it has some limitations too !